# Android Studio can no longer add SDKs, only JDKs. Why?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-12.04

I've upgraded Android Studio from 0.8.* to 1.0.0 RC2 and finally 1.0. Somewhere between the RC2 and 1.0 Android Studio seems to have lost most of its references to the Android SDK.

Some indicators of this are:

- All Android SDK tools have disappeared from the toolbar
- No longer possible to attach the debugger or run apps from within Android Studio
- In 'Project Structure', the SDKs list shows a list of previously added SDKs but when pressing '+' to add an SDK it only allows me to add JDKs.
- In 'Project Structure', the previously added SDKs show "Unknown SDK home path" with a path to the location of the Android SDK. Editing the field with the '...' gives me a "Select Home Directory for Unknown SDK" and pointing to an Android SDK location and pressing OK shows a warning dialog saying "The selected directory is not a valid home for Unknown SDK".
- The 'android' facet is an unknown facet type

How do I make Android Studio recognize the Android SDK again?

Comment: have you updated the needed files in the sdk manager?

Comment: I've launched the SDK Manager and updated to the latest tools and SDK revision, yes.

Comment: I had the same problem two days ago...I updated all the files in the sdk manager and sync'ed gradle with my project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of research (uninstalling and re-installing) I worked out how to fix it but still I don't know how it happened.

These are the steps:

1. Close your current project
2. Go to Settings
3. Click on Plugins
4. Enable Android Support
5. Follow the wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can right-click the toolbar, and select Customize Menus and Toolbars -> Main Toolbars -> Android.MainToolBarActionGroup. You can also select the SDK Manager and AVD Manager from the Main menu.